# Creating new panel like newyork times

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get hands on over bootstrap css.

i wanted to created responsive recommendation panel looking similar to [Highlights From 2014](http://www.nytimes.com/?WT.z_jog=1)

Here it looks little simlair - http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/9r74Y/16/

but if I text size increased, images goes down. Also I dont feel it responsive when i stratch in-out the screen. See- http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/9r74Y/17/

Any help to improve so that looks like similar with responsive effect. Also in terms of font style if possible.

html :

```
<div class="c1">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="descriptionContainer">
            <span class="main-head"> Life in the Valley of Death  </span>
            <span class="min-head">In Srebrenica, the remains of those killed in the genocide keep turning up, unsettling the reconciliation between Muslims and Serbs.</span>          
        </div>
        <div class="image"> 
            <img class="media-object" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/06/01/magazine/01srebrenica4/mag-01srebrenica-t_CA4-thumbWide.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: add width:75% on .descriptioncontainer

Comment: @SathishS: thanks dude, can you please tell me what is the concept here? does remaining parameter are standard as per responsiveness?

Comment: I don,t know this is perfect one but you used .decriptoncontainer as display:inline-block; so what ever you increased your text its goes line so use some % of width;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
.descriptionContainer{
width:75%;/*add on your css */
}
```

Comment: @Satish: is it possible to make image size responsive even?

Comment: @Satish: could you please help in doing this, much appreciable

Answer (score 1):

check it out my demo.. may be helpful to you [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49y2dtda/)

```css
.item {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    clear: both;

    float: left;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    
}
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image img {
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90px;
}

.descriptionContainer {
    min-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span.main-head {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.min-head {
    color: #898989;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
    <div class="item">
  <div class="image"> 
            <img class="media-object" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/06/01/magazine/01srebrenica4/mag-01srebrenica-t_CA4-thumbWide.jpg">
  </div>
<div class="descriptionContainer">
   <span class="main-head"> Life in the Valley of Death  </span>
            <span class="min-head">In Srebrenica, the remains of those killed in the genocide keep turning up, unsettling the reconciliation between Muslims and Serbs.</span>   
  </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
  
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks dude, can you please tell me what is the concept here? does remaining parameter are standard as per responsiveness?

Comment: i just included float:right in class called "image"..so by using this property content undergoes this property will appear on right of the screen....